# How to unit test a function that returns a promise in angular

Tags: angular, promise, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a function inside a component that will call a service method with 3 arguments and that will return a promise. I want to unit test the function using karma jasmine in angular. Did I make any mistakes here?

component code

```
getHeaderData() {
 return this.service.getList({
    id: this.id,
    name: this.name,
    pageName: constants.PAGE_NAME
  });
}
```

service code

```
getList(param): Promise<any> {
 const params = new HttpParams()
    .set('cId',param.id)
    .set('cName',param.name)
    .set('cPageName',param.pageName);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   try {
       this.httpService.get('getHeader', {params}).subscribe(data => {
         resolve(data);
        });
   }catch (err){
     reject(err);      
    }
 });
}
```

spec file code

```
it('test getHeaderData()', async () => {
  const serviceSpy: Service = TestBed.get(Service);
  SpyOn(serviceSpy, 'getList').and.ReturnValue(Promise.resolve(constants.response));
  expect(serviceSpy.getList).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(component.getHeaderData()).toBe(constants.response);
});
```

the actual return value form the service is an array of objects the same I have created in the constant file as response and with the above code I'm getting below error. I'm not sure this is the right way to do it.

> Argument of type  is missing the following properties form the ' { then: ExpectedRecursive<{< TResult1 etc......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Everything looks good, you've just missed the `await` keyword, because you're returning a `Promise` of `constants.response` (`Promise<constants.response>`). Hence, you have to `await` it before verifying.

```js
it('test getHeaderData()', async () => {
  const serviceSpy: Service = TestBed.get(Service);
  SpyOn(serviceSpy, 'getList').and.ReturnValue(Promise.resolve(constants.response));
  expect(serviceSpy.getList).toHaveBeenCalled();

  // Added missed `await` keyword
  expect(await component.getHeaderData()).toBe(constants.response);
});
```

Comment: I added await as you mentioned but now I'm getting the below two errors
1. Expected spy getList to HaveBeenCalled
2. cannot read property 'id' of null.

Do I need to pass the actual arguments here? If so how to do it here?

Comment: @Yevhen are you able to have a look at my most recent question? I seem to be having issues along the same lines...